# Avoid empty space writing list to text file

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, csv, file-io, whitespace

I'm trying to write the contents of a list into a text file where every item in the list is on a new line without any empty lines in between. My problem seems to be an artifact from creating a large list from items grabbed from looping through multiple csv files and combining them into one list. Maybe I just need to combine the lists differently to fix the "\n" after the individual words but not between lists...?

```
some_list = [] # list of csv files
for i in os.listdir('filepath_to_directory_with_csv_files'):
    some_list.append(i)
print (some_list)
```

['A_test.csv', 'B_test.csv']

```
CombinedList = [] # list containing all the rows in each csv file
for InFileName in some_list: # for loop to capture data from all csv files
    InFile = open(InFileName, 'r')
    PathwayList.append(InFile.readlines())
    InFile.close()  

print (CombinedList)
```

[['This\n', 'is\n', 'A\n', 'test'], ['This \n', 'is\n', 'B\n', 'test']]

```
New_list = [item for sublist in CombinedList for item in sublist]
print (New_list)
```

['This\n', 'is\n', 'A\n', 'test', 'This \n', 'is\n', 'B\n', 'test']

```
with open("CombinedList.txt", "w") as f:

    for line in New_list:
        f.write(line + "\n")
    print('File Successfully written.')
```

File Successfully written.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having double line breaks, You can first strip any '\n' from each line read from the files, then add '\n' to all.

```
PathwayList.append([line.rstrip('\n')+'\n' for line in InFile])
```

output: `[['This\n', 'is\n', 'A\n', 'test\n'], ['This \n', 'is\n', 'B\n', 'test\n']]`

Comment: Note: You'd need to remove the `+ "\n"` from the `f.write` call or you just reliably double line break. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you probably (just a guess because your question in not 100% clear formulated) want is:

```
CombinedList = [['This\n', 'is\n', 'A\n', 'test'], ['This \n', 'is\n', 'B\n', 'test']]
# New_list = ['This\n', 'is\n', 'A\n', 'test', 'This \n', 'is\n', 'B\n', 'test']
for item in CombinedList:
    line = ''
    for word in item:
        line += word.replace('\n', ' ') 
    f.write(line + "\n")
    # print(line)
```

This writes (prints):

```
This is A test
This  is B test
```